# jsGrid has 2 headers when inserting is added

Tags: jsgrid

Forgive me I am new to using the jsGrid so this might be a stupid problem but...
I have a jsGrid with several columns. One column is a date field. I want to add a date picker instead of the input field for it now.
I added the code for the date picker and ran the code and now the jsGrid has 2 headers. One with the input field for the date and the one below with the date picker. I found that as soon as I add inserting: true that is when the 2 headers show.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Here is my code.

```
$(function () {
    var MyDateField = function (config) {
        jsGrid.Field.call(this, config);
    };

    MyDateField.prototype = new jsGrid.Field({
        sorter: function (date1, date2) {
            return new Date(date1) - new Date(date2);
        },

        itemTemplate: function (value) {
            return new Date(value).toDateString();
        },

        insertTemplate: function (value) {
            return this._insertPicker = $("<input>").datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
        },

        editTemplate: function (value) {
            return this._editPicker = $("<input>").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date(value));
        },

        insertValue: function () {
            return this._insertPicker.datepicker("getDate").toISOString();
        },

        editValue: function () {
            return this._editPicker.datepicker("getDate").toISOString();
        }
    });
    jsGrid.fields.myDateField = MyDateField
```

$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            width: "100%",
            inserting: true,
            filtering: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            rowClass: function (item, itemIndex) {

```
            if (item.DisplayOrder == 1) {
                return 'past-due'
                    }
                    if (item.DisplayOrder == 2) {
                        return 'second-notice'
                    }

        pageButtonCount: 5,
        controller: controller,
        fields: [{
            name: "Task Number",
            type: "number",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                return $("<a>").attr("href", "TaskDetail.aspx?id=" + value).text(value);
            },
            align: "center"
        }, {
            name: "Requirement",
            type: "text",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                return $("<a>").attr("href", "RequirementDetail.aspx?id=" + item.req_id).text(value);
            },
            width : "350px"
        }, {
            name: "MERM",
            type: "text",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                return $("<a>").attr("href", "MERM_Detail.aspx?id=" + item.merm_id).text(value);
            }
        }, {
            name: "Due Date",
            type: "myDateField",
            width: 80,
            align: "center"
        }, {
            name: "Action Required",
            type: "select",
            items: actions,
            valueField: "name",
            textField: "name"
        }, {
            name: "Workflow Step",
            title: "Workflow Step",
            type: "select",
            align: "center",
            items: workflowsteps2,
            valueField: "id",
            textField: "DisplayName"
        }, {
            name: "Status",
            type: "select",
            align: "center",
            items: statii2,
            valueField: "id",
            textField: "DisplayName"
        }, {

            name: "Importance",
            type: "select",
            items: importances,
            valueField: "id",
            textField: "DisplayName",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                return $("<div>").addClass(item.Importance == 1 ? 'critical-importance' : item.Importance == 2 ? 'high-importance' : item.Importance == 3 ? 'low-importance' : '').text(item.Importance == 1 ? 'Critical' : item.Importance == 2 ? 'High' : item.Importance == 3 ? 'Low' : '');
            }


        }, {
            visible:false,
            name: "Marked Ready for Review Date",
            type: "text",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                if (value === "NULL") {
                    return "";
                }
                return value;
            }
        }, {
            visible:false,
            name: "QA Completed Date",
            type: "text",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                if (value === "NULL") {
                    return "";
                }
                return value;
            }
        }, {
            name: "Completed Date",
            type: "text",
            itemTemplate: function (value, item) {
                if (value === "NULL") {
                    return "";
                }
                return value;
            }
        }],
        onDataLoaded: function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
```

});
}

The "Due Date" is the field I am talking about.

Thank you for the help.